# How to bind winforms combobox to a simple list of strings?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, combobox

Say we have a `Customer` form whose properties include a plain string field of `Country`.

The below code works in that it writes the changed value back to the underlying data source correctly. But on first displaying it fails to pick up the customer's country; the combobox only ever shows Albania.

```vb
Dim bs As New BindingSource(New List(Of String)(New String() {"Albania", "Belgium", "Chile"}), Nothing)
With CountryComboBox
    .DataSource = bs
    .DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedValue", CustomerBindingSource, "Country", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation))
End With
```

I'm not setting DisplayMember and ValueMember because that doesn't apply to a simple list of strings. But perhaps I should?

Comment: Try to remove the .DataBindings line. I think you don't need it

Comment: @Steve i surely need it if i want the underlying Customer.Country field to be read & written to

Comment: Do you want it to be blank? Or? Is there non-null underlying data? Hard for others to test bindings issues, perhaps someone will recognize the problem.

Comment: @rheitzman i want it to pick up the customer's country

Comment: Do you need to force update after binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing "SelectedValue" inside New Binding with "**SelectedItem**".